# Rails [Grape::API] How to include meta object when using error! method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-grape, grape-api

I am using `Grape::API` gem to build APIs and responses.

I figured a way to add the `meta` object to the response body when responding using `present` method. It is something like this:

```rb
present meta: { key: "value" }
present user, with: UserEntity
```

However, when I want to add the `meta` object with an error using this:

```rb
present meta: { key: "value" }
error!("Error message", 422)
```

I do not get the `meta` object in the response body. How do I add the `meta` object?

---

P.S: Currently I have defined a hack-ish method:

```rb
def present_error(message, status_code, meta: nil)
  body = {}
  body[:errors] = [{ title: message }]
  body[:meta] = meta if meta

  status status_code
  present body
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is nice solution like the one with `present` here.

Probably best you can do is:

```
error!({ error: "Error message", meta: meta }, 422)
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the only solution. I doesn't seem possible to have top-level `meta` and `errors`. But, I didn't know that the `errors` object too can hold a `meta` object.